# How do I create a file with boost filesystem without opening it

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

In boost filesystem there is a function `create_directory` which creates a directory. How do I create a file? I could create one by defining a `boost::filesystem::ofstream` object but that would also open the file, so I would have to call `close` on it before I could do other stuff to it, like renaming or deleting. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boost Filesystem V3 doesn't provide a `touch(1)` function;

Even `touch` will creat+close a file, just look at the output of `strace`:

```
open("/tmp/q", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 47
dup2(47, 0)                             = 0
close(47)                               = 0
utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)             = 0
```

I think your most reasonable bet is to just create a wrapper function that closes the file.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use something like

```
    // ... code ...
    boost::filesystem::ofstream( "/path/to/file" );
    boost::filesystem::rename( "/path/to/file", "/path/to/renamed_file" );
    // ... code ...
```

which will create an empty file and immediately rename it, without a need to close it at any point.